# Trouble with if statements, returning a syntaxerror

Tags: r, if-statement, blackjack

I'm programming blackjack and trying to input rules for the dealer. The code I've got is as follows

```
if sum(dealer$cards<17){
  dealer=twist(dealer)
}else if sum(dealer$cards>17){
    dealer=stick(dealer)
}else{
    dealer
}
```

This returns an error message Error: unexpected '}' in "}". In the script it also states "unexpected token 'sum', expected 'LPAREN'.
Not sure where I am going wrong? Maybe because it's late I just can't see it.

Comment: Try changing `sum(dealer$cards<17)` to `(sum(dealer$cards)<17)` and `sum(dealer$cards>17)` to `(sum(dealer$cards)>17)`

Comment: I know nothing about R, but in C you need parens around the condition of an `if` statement.

Comment: Yes, same in R. So the condition should be: `if (sum(dealer$cards)>17) {`. The other conditions also need to be wrapped in parentheses.